# Working around Active Directory's dynamic port range

Tags: networking, proxy, active-directory

I have a need to authenticate users against Active Directory ([which uses dynamic ports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(WS.10).aspx)), but the networking group within the organization will not allow us to open up such a large range of ports.

I realize that the owner of AD could putz around with registry keys to restrict it to one port, but that isn't going to fly either.

Is there a way to proxy the traffic such that only 1 port is open on the firewall to accept authentication requests and interact with an AD Domain Controller?

**Clarification**

There is a firewall between two networks, where the application on one network needs to utilize AD that is hosted on another.

Comment: why not use a VPN?